# Fetch value between 2 characters from a string

Tags: regex, powershell

I am getting below string as output

```
RX Power:    -3.4    dBm (460.9uW)
```

I tried below code but I am getting output like

```
:    -3.4    d
```

I want output

```
-3.4
```

```
$pattern = '(?s)\:.*? d+'
[regex]::Matches($RXTX_Data[0], $pattern).Value
```

Please let me know what is missing here

Comment: What part(s) of the string do you want to extract exactly?

Comment: @Theo: Sorry didn't mentioned that. I want to extract the value. `-3.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\s(-?\d+.?\d+)\s` for your pattern.

---

- \s for whitespace character on either side of number
- -? for checking if '-' is in number group
- .? for checking if '.' is in number group
- \d+ for matching 1 or more numbers in number group
- () for specifying the group you wish to capture i.e. the number group

---

It worked for me on https://regex101.com. If you haven't heard of it, it's a good place to practice regex.

Answer (score 1):

(Assumed you are looking to get the dBm value)

You can just select the text between the keywords using.

`RX Power:(.*)dBm`

This will give you an answer that includes the spaces (leading and trailing) - but you can easily remove those.

```
$pattern = 'RX Power:(.*)dBm'
[regex]::Matches($RXTX_Data[0], $pattern).Value.Replace(" ","")
```

I'm sure you could remove it in regex as well but I could only get the leading spaces removed using:

```
RX Power:\s*(.*)dBm
```

Comment: To remove trailing spaces too: `RX Power:\s*(\S+)`. The `\S+` matches non-whitespace sequence.

Comment: To extract the value (captured by group) it should be `[regex]::Matches($RXTX_Data[0], $pattern).Groups[1].Value`